# Vertical chapter title in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, vertical-alignment, chapters

I'm about to write my thesis, and finally decided to do so in LaTeX. I'm still new to it though, and was wondering if something like this is possible in the table of contents:

```
--+
  |  
I |  
N |  Topic 1 ................ 1
T |  Topic 2 ................ 3
R |      Subtopic 1 ......... 4
O |  
  |  
--+  
  |  
T |  Topic 3 ................ 6
H |  Topic 4 ................ 8
E |      Subtopic ........... 9
O |          Subsub ......... 11
R |  ... etc
Y |    
  |  
--+
```

The lines used on the left should not be ASCII characters if possible, and the text on the left is the chapter names, in case it isn't clear :-)

**Edit**

Okay, so I will attach a mwe here, although it really doesn't make sense in it's current form.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book} 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Intro}
    \section{Topic 1}
    \section{Topic 2}
        \subsection{Subtopic 1}
\chapter{Theory}
    \section{Topic 3}
    \section{Topic 4}
        \subsection{Subtopic}
            \subsubsection{Subsub}
    \section{... etc}
\end{document}
```

This will produce the following TOC, where I'd like to move the chapter names (Intro and Theory) to the side, as shown in my ASCII graphics above.

[image: MWE output]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Remove this small burden between you and the people who want to help you ;)

Comment: I would if I had any idea how to do it. I'm requesting a pointer to some starting point, as I have no idea how to achieve the above :)

Comment: @Tagger That's not a problem. You can just add a small compilable document with the chapters and sections of your mockup and a table of contents. Any starting point helps :)

Comment: @Harald I've edited my question to add a MWE now :)

Comment: Before you spend much time on this I would recommended checking the formatting requirements of your university and of the thesis archiving service they use. Unfortunately, these requirements do not usually allow for such creativity.

Comment: Also, if you're new to LaTeX I would put off such things to the absolute end of your project.

Comment: @AndrewCashner You definately got a point here. I will check it before submitting it, at least I know HOW to achieve it now if allowed and it makes sense to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See alternate presentation below, for a perhaps superior appearance.

ORIGINAL PRESENTATION

This is a question of **can**, not **should**.  First, reading vertical text is not easy on the eyes.  Second, if the chapter title is too long, you may require an abbreviation to make it fit the vertical space allocated for the toc listing.

So, I approach it with the optional argument, as

```
\chapter[\boxtoc{T h e o r y}{4}]{Theory}
```

where `\boxtoc{}{}` is the macro that sets the title vertically in the toc, the 1st argument is a possibly abbreviated chapter title that is space separated (with more work, I could have the macro deal with that), and the 2nd argument is how many `\baselineskip` you wish to allocate for the vertical box; however, if the chapter name is too long, it could grow the vertical extent of the box beyond that allocated by argument `#2\baselineskip`.

To accomplish its goal, `\boxtoc` uses an `\llap` of an `\fbox`ed stack.  The stack is placed in a fixed-width `\makebox`, to insure that all vertical chapter titles are a uniform width.

This approach will screw up `book` class headers, unless special provisions are taken, but I leave that fix to someone else.

EDITED to blot out the chapter number with a white-block overlay.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage{stackengine,color}
\setstackgap{L}{.75\baselineskip}
\newcommand\boxtoc[2]{%
 \smash{\llap{\fbox{\protect\rule[-#2\baselineskip]{0pt}{#2\baselineskip}%
   \protect\makebox[2ex]{\Longunderstack{#1}}}%
  \kern\fboxrule\usebox{\whiteblock}}}%
}
\newsavebox\whiteblock
\savebox\whiteblock{\textcolor{white}{\protect\rule{.3in}{2ex}}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter[\boxtoc{I n t r o}{3}]{Intro}
    \section{Topic 1}
    \section{Topic 2}
        \subsection{Subtopic 1}
\chapter[\boxtoc{T h e o r y}{4}]{Theory}
    \section{Topic 3}
    \section{Topic 4}
        \subsection{Subtopic}
            \subsubsection{Subsub}
    \section{... etc}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: For some reason, this method is incompatible with the `xcolor` package; however, it works fine with the `color` package.

---

ALTERNATIVE PRESENTATION

Thanks to JúdaRonén in comment, the suggestion was made to rotate the Latin text.  In my estimation, the look is superior.  In this case, there should not be spaces introduced in the optional chapter names.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\newcommand\boxtoc[2]{%
 \smash{\llap{\fbox{%
   \protect\Rotatebox{\protect\makebox[#2\baselineskip][r]{\strut#1}}}%
  \kern\fboxrule\protect\Whiteblock}}%
}
\def\Rotatebox#1{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{#1}}
\def\Whiteblock{\textcolor{white}{\protect\rule{.3in}{2ex}}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter[\boxtoc{Intro}{3}]{Intro}
    \section{Topic 1}
    \section{Topic 2}
        \subsection{Subtopic 1}
\chapter[\boxtoc{Theory}{4}]{Theory}
    \section{Topic 3}
    \section{Topic 4}
        \subsection{Subtopic}
            \subsubsection{Subsub}
    \section{... etc}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Tagger Glad to have helped.

Comment: Aw, maybe except for those bold 1 and 2 next to the box :)

Comment: @Tagger Ask and it shall be given.

Comment: I think that for the Latin script using `rotatebox` will give a more readable output. It will require tilting of the head, though…

Comment: @JúdaRonén I would agree, though the OP didn't ask for it.  Perhaps, if I have a moment, I provide it as an alternative.

Comment: @JúdaRonén  Thanks for that wonderful suggestion.

Comment: @Tagger Please see alternative presentation, thanks, to suggestion by JúdaRonén.

Comment: @Tagger I found one way to resolve the screwed up chapter headers when using `\boxtoc`.  In your preamble, provide definitions like `\def\three{3}\def\four{4}`.  Invoke `\boxtoc` as follows: `\chapter[\boxtoc{Intro}{\three}]{Intro}` and the final thing is to `\let\boxtoc\relax\let\three\relax\let\four\relax` immediately after the `\tableofcontents`.